# Puppet : Copy files only IF the package needs to be installed to the latest

Tags: puppet, redhat

I'm a puppet beginner - so bear with me :)
I'm trying to write a module that does the following :

- Check if a package is installed with the latest version in the repos
- If the package needs to be installed, then config files will be copied from puppet source location, to client. Then the package will be installed
- Once files are copied and package installed, run the script that will use the config files on the client to apply the necessary settings.
- Once all of this are done, remove the copied files on client

I've come up with the following :

```
class somepackage(
  $package_files_base = "/var/tmp",
  $package_setup      = "/var/tmp/package-setup.sh",
  $ndc_file           = "/var/tmp/somefile.ndc",
  $osd_file           = "/var/tmp/somefile.osd",
  $nds_file           = "/var/tmp/somefile.nds",
  $configini_file     = "/var/tmp/somefile.ini",
  $required_files     = ["$package_setup", "$ndc_file", "$osd_file",  $nds_file", "$configini_file"])
{
  package { 'some package':
    ensure  => 'latest',
    notify  =>  Exec['Package Setup'],
  }

  file { 'Package Setup Files':
    path    => $package_files_base,
    ensure  => directory,
    replace => false,
    recurse => true,
    source  => "puppet:///modules/somepackage/${::domain}",
    mode    => '0755',
  }

  exec { 'Package Setup':
    command     => "$package_setup",
    logoutput   => true,
    timeout     => 1800,
    require     => [ File['Package Setup Files']],
    refreshonly => true,
    notify      => Exec['Remove config files'],
  }

  exec { 'Remove config files':
    path        => ['/usr/bin','/usr/sbin','/bin','/sbin'],
    command     => "rm \"${package_setup}\" \"${ndc_file}\" \"${osd_file}\" \"${nds_file}\" \"${configini_file}\"",
    refreshonly => true,
  }
}
```

While this achieves most of what I want to do, I notice that upon rerunning puppet apply the files, although they were being removed, were being recopied.

I can understand why this happens, but I don't know how to code it so that the files get copied ONLY if the package gets updated/installed (e.g. package wasn't installed or old). Otherwise the files will get copied over and over again every time puppet runs every 30 min (default setup) on the client I assume... I tried using the `replace => false` to prevent this but that just means the files wont ever get removed from `/var/tmp` after the first run of the class, because it only prevents subsequent runs of the class to re-copy the files (from my testing). This does prevent the redundant, repetitive copying - however I just want the files to be gone the first time!

Is this possible? Head hurts :(

Thanks in advance! We're running Puppet version 3.8.6 on EL7.3.

EDIT: To be clear, this is the bit that I'm struggling with: the resource `file { 'Package Setup Files':`. This keeps getting files copied even though the package isn't updated/installed. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: From what I understand, you want "Package Setup Files" to execute only if the package is not latest right? Thats the only problem you are facing?

Comment: No, that executes fine - the "file { 'Package Setup Files'" bit is the one that keeps getting executed no matter what. I would like to limit this ONLY IF the package is updated/installed.

Comment: I notice that $package_files_base is not defined anywhere. Typo?

Comment: Is something in your setup scripts coming along and changing files in /var/tmp after you mirror it in the File['Package Setup Files'] step?

Comment: No, the script just reads the config files and configure the application to act in a certain way. But the files themselves dont change content-wise (timestamps might change though)

Comment: Yep, Ok. I see the problem. It is not possible to do what you are trying to do. I will have a think about it. In the meantime, any reason why you can't just install the setup files in /opt somewhere and leave them there?

Comment: I could I guess, but I'd like it to be cleaner if I can..if only there is a "refreshonly" for file resource...why isnt there any? :(

Comment: @SueZ: Thats what I said, see you are removing the files after installing the package, `replace => false` will not replace it if files are present, but since files are removed, it will copy it again. You have not configured `notify` for `file { 'Package Setup Files'` and hence it is getting executed with every puppet run.

Comment: Hi Atmesh, sorry about that. Yes I did try it with notify, by calling it within the resource "package { 'some package': ". However for some reason, it keeps re-copying the file no matter what - even if the package doesnt need updated/install. I think it doesnt work properly because there's no "refreshonly"  with file resource? Not sure.

Comment: Also, Yes, the "replace => false" did work if the files arent removed by "exec { 'Remove config files':" - and I can get rid of this exec resource altogether and did - however this just means the files just remained there on client and not getting cleaned up. But at least the next puppet update it wont recopy indeed (if I remove the exec { 'Remove config files' resource from the manifest).

Comment: The reason there is no "refreshonly" for a file is because there is no "refresh" for a file. In the mean time, I am still thinking about your options for re-engineering this.

Comment: @SueZ: One more question, how do you know that the files are getting recopied, if the files are already there? `replace => false` will ensure that changes in files at source are not reflected at destination. But it will still re-initialise the files in that location. A work-around could be that you can use `exec` and copy files only if it is not present already.

Comment: @SueZ You should be doing the post-install configuration within the `%post` of the package. If this is not a package you own, then you should probably approach this differently.

Comment: Hi Matt, what do you mean by post install within %post of the package? Is this done within the manifest? sorry I'm a newbie...and also sorry for late reply, was off sick..you guys have been so helpful, thanks!

Comment: +1 for fixing the problem in `%post`. @SueZ he means this https://wiki.mageia.org/en/Packagers_RPM_tutorial#Pre-_and_Post-installation_scripts  I assume that you probably didn't create this RPM yourself but if you did, definitely fix it in the RPM post install rather than have Puppet do the post install logic.

Comment: @SueZ Yeah sorry, I meant in the post install section of the linux package that you are installing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some suggestions.

**1) Recommendation for a short term solution**

Stop trying to clean up those files if you do not need to. Put them in `/opt` and forget about them. Better still, have Puppet place a README file in there with them that will explain to your future self and to your fellow admins what they are and why they are there.

While I completely understand the desire to clean up, you need to weigh the cost of having a few old files in a directory somewhere against the cost of having complicated logic in the Puppet code that will not make any sense to anyone in a few months.

This is what I would do and in my experience it is also what most Puppet module authors do with these sorts of set up files.

**2) Consider an orchestration framework**

That said, it appears to me that you are trying to use Puppet to do operational tasks, and while it can kind of do operational tasks (via features like `ensure => latest` etc) it is really intended to be a configuration management tool.

I recommend people use Puppet to `ensure => installed` for packages (make sure Puppet can install the app properly if you need to fully rebuild the node); then delegate the problem of applying version upgrades and hotfixes etc outside of Puppet.

There are a few reasons for this.

Puppet is a declarative configuration management system; your Puppet code should define an end-state. Puppet is not like a shell script, where instead of an end-state, you define steps that change the state of a server imperatively, "one step at a time".

The first problem with `ensure => latest` is philosophical. 
`latest` does not define a single end-state. The behaviour of your code at time X is different from the behaviour at time Y. So your code is not idempotent.

The second problem is practical. You can never solve the problem of RPM updates in a general way using Puppet, because Puppet can never know about all of the RPMs and their dependencies in your system. So, one way or another, you still need a specialised tool for managing the version updates.

So, since you will need a specialised tool for managing the version updates anyway, it is cleaner to draw a clear boundary between the two tools' roles: always use Puppet to manage the *configuration* and the initial installation; and then always use the other tool to manage the updates.

Ok, great. I see in your comments that you already have a Red Hat Satellite server, and you have written:

> ...some hosts within the Satellite have got an older version of the
>   software within yum. But we don't update this software very
>   often.....maybe once every year.

So, it sounds like you are using Puppet here to work around a problem in the way you are using Satellite. Is it possible to address this by fixing the way you use Satellite? If so, I think that will be cleaner.

Of course, sometimes the right thing to do is use a work-around, and that's why I provided some other options.

**3) If you really really want Puppet to clean up those files**

Perhaps move the logic inside a shell script. Something like:

```
class somepackage {

  $shell =

'#!/bin/bash

# maybe use wget instead of puppet to get the files
wget http://a.b/c.tgz
tar zxf c.tgz

# install stuff

# clean up stuff
'

  file { '/usr/local/bin/installer.sh':
    ensure  => file,
    mode    => '0755',
    content => $shell,
  }

  package { 'some package':
    ensure => latest,
    notify => Exec['installer'],
  }

  exec { 'installer':
    command     => '/usr/local/bin/installer.sh',
    refreshonly => true,
    require     => File['/usr/local/bin/installer.sh'],
  }
}
```

Comment: She is not trying to do orchestration, but points 1 and 3 are still valid.

Comment: It depends how you define "orchestration", but I can tell you no less an authority than Nigel Kersten (Puppet CTO) shares my view that you should not ever use Puppet's `ensure => latest` (IIRC, Melbourne Puppet Camp, 2014); this is an operational/server maintenance task, and best handled by the orchestration framework outside of Puppet.

Comment: He probably said "try to avoid" rather than "not ever".

Comment: Ok, @MattSchuchard, I added some more to point 2. Let me know if that makes more sense?

Comment: Doing `ensure => latest` has nothing to do with orchestration and is also irrelevant to my comment. Also, the answer was fine already with points 1 and 3 which is why I upvoted it.

Comment: It depends on how it is defined, e.g. if you go with the definition at https://devops.com/automation-versus-orchestration/  it means "...automation of a workflow or process". We have a workflow, which might be the monthly security updates. Whatever you call it, though, it's really really hard to get Puppet to be a general replacement for a monthly yum update. So I try to warn people that there are better tools out there that do this stuff.

Comment: Thank you Alex for your contribution on this! What you said made sense..but can you explain further why ensure=>latest isn't recommended, and in which situation should it be used? This module that I'm trying to write, is for an installation for a non-redhat (coming from 3rd party vendor) software...I used ensure=>latest because some hosts within the Satellite have got an older version of the software within yum. But we don't update this software very often.....maybe once every year? so I thought using ensure=>latest would suffice.

Comment: Also, why did you recommend wget instead of puppet? I thought this would be a cleaner way. Hope you can elaborate :) Thanks!

Comment: @SueZ I changed the second part of my answer in light of the additional information you provided here in the comments. Let me know if that now makes sense.

Comment: @SueZ re wget instead of Puppet. Almost anything that will allow you to avoid specifying a complicated ordering in Puppet via a string of execs is probably cleaner. At the end of the day, I consder "clean" to be something other humans can understand. We spend 10% of our time writing code, and 90% trying to understand code that someone else wrote. Keep-it-simple. If you use puppet `recurse => true` you still have the problem that your shell script can't clean it up without Puppet putting it back on the next run. Of course, I have assumed you have an HTTP server.

Comment: Thanks Alex...that makes better sense thank you :) appreciate you taking the time to explain.